# Creating rails model from nested JSON request - AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, restkit

My application has the following model classes:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
    attr_accessible :child_attributes, :child

    has_one :child

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :child

    #This is to generate a full JSON graph when serializing
    def as_json(options = {})
        super(options.merge, :include => {:child => {:include => :grandchild } })
    end
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
    attr_accessible :grandchild_attributes, :grandchild

    belongs_to :parent
    has_one :grandchild

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :grandchild
end

class Grandchild < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :child
end
```

The, in my controller i have a `create` method, defined as follows:

```
def create
    @parent = Parent.new(params[:parent])
    #Rest ommited for brevity - just respond_with and save code
    end
end
```

My request is showing up in the logs as:

```
Parameters: {"parent"=>{"child"=>{"grandchild"=>{"gc_attr1"=>"value1", "gc_attr2"=>"value2"}}, "p_attr1"=>"value1"}
```

Which is the full serialization graph that came from my iphone app client that uses RestKit.
I have seen on other SO questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527542/creating-a-nested-json-request-with-rails) , thats refers to [this](http://www.rogue-development.com/blog2/2009/05/creating-nested-objects-with-json-in-rails/) blog post.
My problem, however is that I don't know how to control the serialized graph from my client side using RestKit in order to build a request like this (and that way, it works.. tested with debugger)

```
Parameters: {"parent"=>{"child_attributes"=>{"grandchild_attributes"=>{"gc_attr1"=>"value1", "gc_attr2"=>"value2"}}, "p_attr1"=>"value1"}
```

Anyone have ideas if there is any option I can pass on to the Parent.new method or customize the RestKit JSON output in a way that I may achieve the model_attributes structure within nested JSON objects?

Thanks

Comment: What did the blog post say? The link is dead and I don't speak Objective C!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl), which is a gem to render json as views. Awesome work.
This allowed me to customize the serialization graph of my model.

On RestKit side (using OM2.0 - new object mapping), I have changed my mappings all to `child_attributes` for all relationships, for instance:

```
RKObjectMapping* parentMapping = ... //Initialize your mapping here
RKObjectMapping* childMapping  = ... //Initialize your mapping here

//Configure mapping relationship with child
[parentMapping  mapKeyPath:@"child_attributes" toRelationship:@"childProperty" withObjectMapping:childMapping];

//Register mappings
RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[manager.mappingProvider registerMapping:parentMapping withRootKeyPath:@"parent"];
[manager.mappingProvider registerMapping:childMapping withRootKeyPath:@"child"];
```